# How to convert data in cassandra commitlogs to readable format

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Is it possible to see data in commit-log, if so how can we convert this to readable form which we can interpret.

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is check out CASSANDRA-8844

Answer (score 0):

Commit log files, these are encrypted files maintained internally by Cassandra, so you won't be able to access them.

**Uses of Commit log:**

If Cassandra was writing these SSTables on every update it would be completely IO bound and very slow.
So Cassandra uses a few tricks to get better performance. Instead of writing SSTables to disk on every column update, it keeps the updates in memory and flushes those changes to disk periodically to keep the IO to a reasonable level.